# Llenar una base de datos MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

¡Hola!
Estoy creando un sistema de vacantes y postulaciones a puestos de trabajo. Cuando un usuario se inscribe, puede ver las vacantes activas y puede postularse a las que desee. Luego de postularse, debe ***priorizar*** entre 1 y 3 las que más le llamen la atención. En estoy último está mi problema.

Consulto a la Base de Datos las postulaciones del usuario, hasta aquí no hay lío, pero cuando quiero que se cargue la priorización, no me funciona. En la base de datos no me actualiza la priorización.

**Aquí hago la consulta con WHILE**
Hago la consulta y traigo los datos de las postulaciones *(vacantes)* a través de un WHILE.

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);

session_start();
$us = $_SESSION["us_sesion"];
$postulante = $us;

include ("../../../BaseDatos/conectar.php");

$con = conectar_bd();

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM postulaciones INNER JOIN vacantes WHERE postulaciones.postulante = '$us' AND postulaciones.postulacion = vacantes.id";

$resultado = $con->query($consulta);

if ($resultado -> num_rows > 0) {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../Img/favicon.png">
    <title>
        TCN - LCF
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../Estilos/estilo.css">

</head>
<body>  
    <h1><img src="../../../Img/escudo_LCF.gif" width="11%">
    </h1>
    <h1>MIS POSTULACIONES: </h1>
    <p>Por favor, prioriza cada una de las vacantes aplicadas.</p>
    <form name="priorizacion" method="post" action="GuardaPostulaciones.php">
        <table border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Categoría de la postulación
                </th>
                <th>
                    Área de la postulación
                </th>
                <th>
                    Nombre de la postulación
                </th>
                <th>
                    Priorización
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="postulacion" value="<?php echo $fila['id'];?>">
                    <?php echo $fila['cat_vacante'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $fila['are_vacante'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $fila['nom_vacante'];?>
                </td>
              <td>
              <select class="sel" name="priorizar">
                          <option>PRIORIZACIÓN</option>
                            <option value="primera">
                                Primera
                            </option>
                          <option value="segunda">
                            Segunda
                          </option>
                          <option value="tercera">
                            Tercera
                          </option>
                        </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
            ?>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="postulante" value="<?php echo($postulante);?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Priorizar">
    </form>
    
    <p class="hiper_botones">
        <form name="regreso" method="post" action="../VerVacantes/ConsultarVacantes/index.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $us;?>">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Regresar">
        </form>
    </p>
    </body>
</html>


<?php
    //Cierra la conexión
      $resultado->free();
      mysqli_close($con);
        } else {
    ?>
<h2> ¡Atención! </h2>
    <p>
        Aun no tienes postulaciones registradas con nosotros
</p>
            <form name="regreso" method="post" action="../VerVacantes/ConsultarVacantes/index.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $us;?>">
                <input type="submit" name=""value="Regresar">
            </form>
        </p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
         }
?>
```

**Aquí intento hacer el UPDATE**
Tomo los valores de la priorización desde el código anterior y se debería guardar en la base de datos, teniendo en cuenta el id de la vacante.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

session_start();
$us = $_SESSION["us_sesion"];

$postulante = $_POST['postulante'];
$postulacion = $_POST['postulacion'];
$primera = $_POST['primera'];
$segunda = $_POST['segunda'];
$tercera = $_POST['tercera'];

include("../../../BaseDatos/conectar.php");

$con = conectar_bd();

$sql = "UPDATE `postulaciones` SET `primera` = '$primera', `segunda` = '$segunda', `tercera` = '$tercera' WHERE postulante = '$postulante'";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../Img/favicon.png">
    <title>
        TCN - LCF
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../Estilos/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <h2> ¡Atención! </h2>
    <p> Hemos almacenado tu postulación en nuestro sistema.</p>
    <p>Por favor, consúltala en el botón <strong>MIS POSTULACIONES.</strong></p>
    <p>
            <form name="regreso" method="post" action="../VerVacantes/ConsultarVacantes/index.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $us;?>">
                <input type="submit" name=""value="Regresar">
            </form>
        </p>

</body>
</html>

<?php
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

No sé como cargar cada uno de los datos que corresponden para llenar mi tabla.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No tengo tan claro tu problema, pero creo que entendi, que no te cargan las prioridades del select, si ese es el problema prueba a intentar: `<option value="primera" <?php if($fila['primera']=='primera'){ ?> selected <?php } ?> >Primera</option>`